# curve to dome,?

Tags: extrude

[image]
how to:

Draw a line down middle to split halves

Make faces and 'rotate extrude' into a dome?

How to cut out and hollow the dome?
How to offset by X thickness to define shell i.e. add X thickness everywhere

*is very new to this*

Know a channel covering basic geometry tutorials like this?
Thankyou if you can help :~)

Comment: If you want more than basic curves go to Edit -> preferences -> Addons and find Extra: Curves(or something like that) I will give you more options, even to make dome with simple curve... Also does it need to be curve? You can simply do it with sphere

Answer (score 6):

The 'Rotate Extrude' (Lathe) tool in Blender is the *Screw* modifier, which is available for curves, as well as meshes:

[image]

(The yellow curve is a copy, bevelled for visibility in the illustration.)

Depending on your resolution settings, etc. in the curve, (maybe have a play with those, to get the hang of them) if / when it's converted to a mesh, the result is something like this:

[image]

You can then add thickness with a *Solidify* modifier.

There's no doubt, curve editing is not Blender's strongest point; it requires a few learned tricks to be reasonably fluent.

For the dome as shown, X across, Z up:

- The origin of the curve is at World 0
- The type of the 2 control points is 'Aligned'
- With 3D Cursor at World 0, and set to be the Pivot Point, the control points are <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> flattened to the XZ plane
- With the Pivot set to 'Median Point' the peak control point has been selected, and <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> made horizontal. The rim control point has been <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> made vertical.

Then the *Screw* modifier has been assigned:

[image]

Here's a [Blend File](https://pasteall.org/blend/1bb32c5f7de3431cb93916a635cb2552):

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.. this is closest I can get 
 with screw modifier 
https://imgur.com/S3pscmc

Comment: 4 minutes in Robin's time is equivalent to days in mine. Still cannot model a dome :/ please walk me through it sir

Comment: @absolute_schmuck .. see edit. ( BTW, thanks, but no need to 'sir' _me_ of all people :D)

Comment: ... [Brave Sir Robin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZwuTo7zKM8)

Comment: @batFINGER ..8D ... always did like a bit of _Men in Tights_....

Comment: another [Robin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bU6rh7nRDgY&ab_channel=WarnerBros.) , _Oh Errol, I would give anything, just to be like you_

Answer (score 1):

A dome can also be constructed from a primative if you don't NEED to use a curve. Create a cylinder with appropriate number of sides, in edit mode select the end that you want to dome-ify. Hit ctrl-B to bevel, give it a good number of segments, enable clamping with "c" and then bevel it down until you get the curve. Make sure to merge duplicates with m->by distance.

To make it hollow, delete the non-beveled end and add a solidify modifier.
Same effect could be done non-destructively (I think) with a modifier stack of bevel (set to weight and the edges weighted), weld, and then solidify, but I don't know how you'd hollow it out.